# Unit testing a Servlet that depends on Spring's WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, servlets, applicationcontext

I'd like to unit-test a servlet code that relies on Spring's `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context)` in its `init()` method.

Here is part of the code:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
super.init();
WebApplicationContext applicationContext =
    WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
this.injectedServiceBean = (SomeService) applicationContext.getBean("someBean");
}
```

What would be the best way to inject a proper applicationContext.xml (test version) into this text?

I'm aware of Spring's `@ContextConfiguration`, but it I'm not sure about the best approach to inject the `${testClass}Test-context.xml` context that is loaded by that annotation into the servlet context, so that the getRequiredWebApplicationContext(...) can return it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inject application context in the following way:

```
getServletContext().setAttribute(
  WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE,
  testApplicationContext
);
```

This works because `WebApplicationContextUtils` fetches an object stored in `ServletContext` with `org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT` key (`WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE` constant).

This only shows that fetching beans directly from an application context is problematic since this approach does not follow DI rules. If you can, try refactoring this servlet to integrate it better with Spring (e.g. using [`HttpRequestHandlerServlet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/HttpRequestHandlerServlet.html) [<sup>see example</sup>](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/tenfold-increase-in-server-throughput.html)).

Comment: can you add an example, probably a complete test ?

Comment: I am getting this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

I had to unit test a servlet filter that accesses application context using this static `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext` utility method.

The previous answer from @Tomasz Nurkiewicz helped me to properly mock the context for tests. As the answer doesn't contain the actual code, I'd like to share my implementation in case it'll be useful for someone in the future.

```
WebApplicationContext applicationContext = mock(WebApplicationContext.class);
HttpSession httpSession = mock(HttpSession.class);
ServletContext servletContext = mock(ServletContext.class);
when(httpSession.getServletContext()).thenReturn(servletContext);
when(servletContext.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE))
    .thenReturn(applicationContext);
when(httpServletRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(httpSession);
```

And in the filter class itself, I retrieve the context with the utility method.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(
    httpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext());
```